# MongoDBでドキュメントの子要素の配列にhashデータを追加したい。

Tags: mongodb

更新したいデータ

```
users = {  
  {_id: 111,
   age: 24,
   live: "Tokyo",
   skill:[
     {
       name: "ruby"
       create_at: "2021-11-11 00:00:00"
     },
     {
       name: "python"
       create_at: "2021-11-12 00:00:00"
     }
   ]
  },
}
```

うまくupdateしつつ、skillの箇所に要素の追加をしたいのですが、うまくいきません。

```
    db.users.updateMany(
      { _id: 111 },
      {
        $push:
          { skill: [{ name: "perl", create_at: "2021-11-13 00:00:00" }] }
      }
    )
```

$pushの箇所を$addToSetにしても追加登録ができませんでした。
何か文法的におかしければご教授いただけると幸いです。

実行ログは正常に通ってるぽいのですが

```
{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

このようにしたいのでしょうか？

◆ 追加前

```
db.users.find();

{ "_id" : 111, "skill" : [ { "name" : "ruby", "create_at" : "2021-11-11 00:00:00" } ] }
```

◆ 追加処理

```
db.users.updateMany(
    { _id: 111 },
    {
        $push: { skill: { name: "perl", create_at: "2021-11-13 00:00:00" } }
    }
)
```

◆ 追加後

```
db.users.find();

{ "_id" : 111, "skill" : [ { "name" : "ruby", "create_at" : "2021-11-11 00:00:00" }, { "name" : "perl", "create_at" : "2021-11-13 00:00:00" } ] }
```